# jfreechart : BarChart total label positioning issue?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using following code to position the total label on the bar chart's bar. The position is supposedly on the top of the each rendered bar. But some reason the label rendering is messing up the entire chart!

*UPDATE Positioning Total Labels issue* The totals for each bar should be on the top-center of the each bar! instead it positioned random somewhere near top and not aligned to bars.[image]

Following lines are trouble having rendering chart lable:

```
ItemLabelAnchor labelAnchor = "O".equals(direction) ? ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12 : ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE8;
TextAnchor textAnchor = "O".equals(direction) ? TextAnchor.TOP_CENTER : TextAnchor.CENTER;
TextAnchor rotationAnchor = "O".equals(direction) ? TextAnchor.TOP_CENTER : TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER;
renderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0,
        new ItemLabelPosition(labelAnchor, textAnchor, rotationAnchor, ((angle * Math.PI) / 180)));
```

I am using jdk 8 with jFreeChart-1.0.19. Following complete code listing:

```
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

if (plot != null) {
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("Total Renderers : " + plot.getRendererCount());
}
try {
    JRPropertiesMap propMap = jasperChart.getPropertiesMap();
    if (propMap.containsProperty(APPLY_LABEL_ROTATION)) {
        DecimalFormat dfKey = new DecimalFormat("###,###");

       /* {0} - label would be equal to Series expression,
       * {1} - label would be equal to Category expression,
       * {2} - label would be equal to Value expression
       */
    StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator labelGenerator = new    StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}", dfKey);

LegendItemCollection lic = new LegendItemCollection();
List<LegendItem> legendList = new ArrayList<LegendItem>();
LegendItem totalOpenLegend = null;
for (int i = 0; i <= (plot.getRendererCount() - 1); i++) {

    String prop = propMap.getProperty("Chart_" + (i + 1));

    Double angle = null == prop ? 0D : Double.valueOf(prop.substring(0, prop.length() - 1));
    String direction = null == prop ? "O" : "" + prop.charAt(prop.length() - 1);
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Property value for renerer : " + i + " Chart_" + (i + 1) + "  angle : " + angle + ", Direction : " + direction);
    }

    CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer(i);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(labelGenerator);

    if (i == 0) {
        Shape shape = ShapeUtilities.createLineRegion(new Line2D.Double(-6, 0, 6, 0), 1);
        ((LineAndShapeRenderer) renderer).setSeriesShape(0, shape);
        ((LineAndShapeRenderer) renderer).setBaseItemLabelsVisible(false);
    }

    if (i == 1) {
        //shape = ShapeUtilities.createLineRegion(new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 1, 1), 2);
        ((LineAndShapeRenderer) renderer).setBaseShapesFilled(false);
        ((LineAndShapeRenderer) renderer).setBaseItemLabelPaint(Color.RED);
    }

    if (i == 2) {
        ((LineAndShapeRenderer) renderer).setBaseItemLabelsVisible(false);
    }

    if (i == 3) {
        ((LineAndShapeRenderer) renderer).setBaseItemLabelPaint(new Color(139, 90, 43));
    }

    LegendItem item = renderer.getLegendItem(i, 0);

    if ((i >= 0) && (i < 4)) {
        legendList.add(item);
    } else {
        totalOpenLegend = item;
        BarRenderer barRenderer = (BarRenderer) renderer;
        barRenderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.3);
        barRenderer.setItemMargin(0.1);
    }

    ItemLabelAnchor labelAnchor = "O".equals(direction) ? ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12 : ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE8;
    TextAnchor textAnchor = "O".equals(direction) ? TextAnchor.TOP_CENTER : TextAnchor.CENTER;
    TextAnchor rotationAnchor = "O".equals(direction) ? TextAnchor.TOP_CENTER : TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER;
    renderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0,
            new ItemLabelPosition(labelAnchor, textAnchor, rotationAnchor, ((angle * Math.PI) / 180)));
    //--
    plot.setRenderer(i, renderer);
}

lic.add(totalOpenLegend);

for (LegendItem li : legendList) {
    lic.add(li);
}
System.out.println("Setting Legend Items");
plot.setFixedLegendItems(lic);
plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0);
```

Comment: In what way are the labels not positioned as you expect? Please clarify exactly what you mean by _"messing up"_; then, edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe but isolates the problem from extraneous elements such as shapes and properties.

Comment: I have edited the problem with annotated screenshot.